# How to run DBT with Cockroach DB?

Tags: python, dbt, cockroachdb

I am building dbt models using multiple database connectors that my organization uses for many cases. We also use CRDB which is the only database not supported by dbt in my organization.
My problem is when trying to create a view or a table using a CRDB connection I get the following error:

I am using the dbt-postgres adapter

I tried checking if there's any transaction running by executing: 'show transaction status' which returned 'NoTxn'  meaning there is no other transaction running.

I tried searching on Google which led me to this open GitHub issue: [LINK](https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/57715)
But I don't see how this solution can be implemented in an organization as ours which large and complex database.

```
Encountered an error:
Database Error
there is already a transaction in progress
```

I was expecting to see the adapter working and managing the transactions alone.

Our CRDB is the center of the organization. We already made full migration to dbt with Airflow. This is our last milestone and I am looking forward to migrate our CRDB.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no official support for DBT with CRDB. There is an open issue on the CRDB Github repo to add it https://github.com/cockroachdb/cockroach/issues/57715.